# Tools and Frameworks required for a new Java web application

Tags: web-applications, frameworks, jakarta-ee

I am starting to develop a new web based Java application. Please suggest a good set of frameworks to start with. The priority is to reduce the development time. But at the same time, I want the application to be highly configurable and modular.

> Crude Specifications:
>   -Huge user base (~1M). Nearly 200 concurrent users.
>   -Write to database are moderate but reads are high.
>   -Role based security
>   -The application should be highly **scalable**.
>   -Object relational mapping required.
>   -Application can be later exposed as web service.

I would be mostly working with open-source/free tool & frameworks.

IDE: Eclipse
Repository: TortoiseSVN
Database: MySQL as of now (but i won't mind switching for better performance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest [Spring Framework](http://www.springsource.com/) as it has everything that you require and more. Using [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/roo) you can quickly start an application and have it up and running with everything you want. I would suggest removing Roo once you are up and running though. At least for now that's what we do. Maybe in time it will mature to the point where we will find it always useful.

The [SpringSource Tools Suite](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts) is eclipse based and very well done.

Comment: Good option. Is there any way I can reduce the development time with Spring?

Comment: It depends. Roo does speed up the initial part of the project, configuring everything and adding entities etc. But I still find that later on you have to do a bit without it.

Comment: Thanks Vincent. I've started looking into it.